# Best way to copy content from one SharePoint instance to another?

Tags: 2010, content-type, document, document-migration

I need to migrate approximately 20k documents from one SharePoint instance to another.  These documents are broken up into about 6 content types in the source instance and will be going into 4 different content types in the new instance (some content types in the old system have been merged).

Does microsoft provide a way to migrate documents over to a new content type and a new instance and provide a way of mapping old columns to new columns?  If not is there a third party tool that will do this?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any specific methods Microsoft provides that handle this. If the existing content types exist in the new farm, perhaps you could first migrate the documents and then [change the item's contenttype property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.contenttype.aspx) with PowerShell or a custom application.

As for commercial products, I think [Metalogix's Migration Manager for SharePoint](http://www.metalogix.com/Products/Migration-Manager-for-SharePoint/SharePoint-Upgrade.aspx) can handle this as it provides the option to map content types from the old to the new locations *(disclosure: the company I work for has a partnership with Metalogix)*. I have only ever performed migrations with Migration Manager where the content types remained unchanged so I can't provide any feedback right now as to whether this is possible. They do have a [free trial](http://www.metalogix.com/Downloads/Migration-Manager-for-SharePoint/SharePoint-Upgrade.aspx) if you're willing to fill their form with fake information (or real information if that's the sort way you browse the internet) and test it out.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Axceler ControlPoint](http://www.axceler.com/Products/ControlPoint.aspx) which has a 'Çopy list items' option. If metadata information (columns) are not mapped from old to new a dropdown dialog will ask you to map the metadata colums of the old location to the colums on the new location.

We only use 2 custom content types, but whenever I move content to the production environment I always get the metadata catalog if colum names are missing or named differently.

ControlPoint is a commercial product that we also use for SharePoint management, maintenance and governance. If you contact Axceler: they are always willing to give online presentations or demos (and they do have [trial licenses](http://snare.axceler.com/programs.nsf/trk?openagent&pid=187) ;-) ).

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint.SE! I can't tell if you are associated with Axceler or not but just in case... we  require disclosure of any affiliation with  products or websites. Please see [May I promote products or websites I  am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines. Since your answer IS on topic, it is OK for now. :)